# Code wrong in version 4.5.0

Tags: jqgrid

I have the following code in 4.4.5

```
    parametrii={addParams: {
    rowID: 'new_row',
    useDefValues: true,
    addRowParams: {
        keys: true,
        oneditfunc: function (rowid) {
            editingRowId = rowid;
        },
        afterrestorefunc: function (id) {
           editingRowId = undefined;
        },
        aftersavefunc : function(rowid,response) {
           var json = $.parseJSON(response.responseText); 
           return [true, eval(json.mesaj),$gridintretinuti.trigger("reloadGrid")];
        }
    }
}
```

and in 4.5.0 not work.
I do not know why, can someone help me ?

this is error: TypeError: can't convert undefined to object

Comment: Can you expand on "Not Work"?

Comment: What's the error? Why do you say it doesn't works?

Comment: Can you provide a complete code sample?  your missing the beginning and ending of the code in the provided sample.

Answer (score 1):

`aftersavefunc` don't need to return anything. Calling of `$gridintretinuti.trigger("reloadGrid")` inside of `aftersavefunc` seems me also very strange. If you really want to reload grid inside of `aftersavefunc` it's better to call `reloadGrid` inside of `setTimeout`. For example

```js
aftersavefunc: function () {
    var $self = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $self.trigger("reloadGrid", [{current: true}]);
    }, 50);
}
```

The changes of code will have sense independent from the version of jqGrid which you use.